# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Accessing image from remote server is working fine If I am loading my page first time or refresh with `(CTRL + SHIFT + R)`. If I refresh the page `(CTRL+R)` all my image request pass through service worker and it is throwing

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value
>   'SAMEORIGIN'.

[image]

Comment: you are passing the wrong token value `SAMEORIGIN` for some header and hence your request is getting denied from server

Comment: something is changing the `origin` **request** header perhaps?

Comment: From the console error its obvious that your remote server has an invalid header value.'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has to take either value '*' to allow all origins or a value 'somdomain.com/some.ip'.In your case the value is set as 'SAMEORIGIN' which to my knowledge is not valid

Comment: check all request and response headers in the browser **developer** tools network console - the answer **will** be there

Comment: `SAMEORIGIN` is a valid value for `X-Frame-Options`, but it has nothing to do with CORS. Your remote server is sending a nonsense response here.